# How can I indicate data frames with for- statement in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out a way to pick up data frames with for statement.
Say, I have 10 data frames with names 'seg 1' ... 'seg 10'.

I want to indicate those data frames with for statement and do things such as summing up the number of rows of the data frames.

I tried paste, like

```
    sum <- NULL;
    for (i in 1:10){
    sum <- sum + dim(paste("seg",i))
```

but I know it's a nonsense for this to work.
would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is not so bad,  but you can't get the number of rows of a string. You need to use `get` to get the variable with the name in the string.   Try:

```
sum <- 0;
for (i in 1:2){
    sum <- sum + nrow(get(paste("seg",i))) }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'd like to add 1 more question; I thought sum <- NULL; and sum<- 0 would give the same result but didn't, it gives numeric(empty) instead. Could you explain why this happens?I thought giving NULL creates an empty space...

Comment: @KyooSungSo At the console try `NULL + 1` vs. `0 + 1`

Comment: @Dason Thanks a lot.